# cannot call method 'set' of undefined ember

Tags: ember.js

I get cannot call method 'set' of undefined object when I remove item from ArrayController.

```
start: function () {
    this.registerModel('listController', Ember.ArrayController.create());
    this._super();
},
```

My view looks like,

```
 {{#each item in marketingListCriteriaList}}          
   {{view Select valueBinding="item.entity" contentBinding="controller.allEntities" optionLabelPath="content.Name" optionValuePath="content.Name"  }}
 {{/each}}
```

I have a observer method which observes 
     .observes('listController.@each.entity')

The above observer gets called when i remove object from array controller using removeObject() method.

Are there any other ways to remove objects from array?

```
entityChangeObserver: function (thisModule) {
    var thisModule = this;
    var criteria = thisModule.get('listController.content');
    if (criteria != undefined && criteria.length > 0 && criteria[criteria.length - 1].entity != undefined) {
        var presentObject = criteria[criteria.length - 1];
        $.each(thisModule.get('allEntities'), function (index, item) {
            if (presentObject.entity === item.Name) {
                presentObject.set('allAttributes', item.Attributes);
            }
        });           
    }
}.observes('listController.@each.entity'),

attributeChangeObserver: function (thisModule) {
    var thisModule = this;
    var criteria = thisModule.get('listController.content');
    if (criteria != undefined && criteria.length > 0 && criteria[criteria.length - 1].attribute != undefined) {
        var presentObject = criteria[criteria.length - 1];
        $.each(presentObject.get('allAttributes'), function (index, item) {
            if (presentObject.attribute === item.Name) {
                thisModule.setDefaulsVisibility(presentObject);
                if (item.Type === '1') {
                    presentObject.set('textVisible', true);
                }
                else if (item.Type === '2') {
                    presentObject.set('selectVisible', true);
                    presentObject.set('allValues', item.Values);                        
                }
                else if (item.Type === '3') {
                    presentObject.set('multiSelectVisible', true);
                    presentObject.set('allValues', item.Values);
                }
                else if (item.Type === '4') {
                    presentObject.set('dateVisible', true);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}.observes('listController.@each.attribute'),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly sorry for the late post.

I figured the solution for the problem "calling set on destroyed object".

In my control definition of **didInsertElement** I made a check for **if (!me.isDestroyed)** for every set operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can also remove array elements using "remove" instead of "removeObject" however, you might want to double check your logic in your observer which gives undefined error when you remove an object. I would recommend sticking to remove object and just fixing the error within the observer. Also, do note that using "remove" will not instantly update handlebar templates if you are looping over the array.

Comment: Sorry for giving the wrong description. The error I get is **calling set on destroyed object**. I've handled undefined exception in my observer.